# Prevent Calling one method before calling another

Tags: java, rest

Can you please share me the standard method, if any to prevent one method call before the client call another. For example: I have the following two methods in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = “/save”, method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public String save(string temp){
    return service.update(temp);
}

@RequestMapping(value = “/save/confirm”, method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public String ValidateInfo(string temp){
    return service.update(temp);
}
```

So the question is what is the standard way to prevent the client side from calling the save method before calling the validateInfo method using REST API features. Assuming both methods do serious of stuff in the server side.

Comment: Create a sentinel value? `if (!canRun){return null;}`

Answer (score 0):

The client, which might be a different piece of software that you don't control, can make any call at any time. So you can't really prevent a client from making calls. This suggests that your design is a bit flawed.

I would suggest validating the user input as part of the save method - this is usually more secure and robust. If the validation fails, you should consider how you want to notify the client. For example, you could return an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a token from method1 which needs to supplied as parameter to method2..In this way you can make sure that method2 is always called after method1